# Detect updates on sectionNameKeyPath from NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, updates

Here is the case. I have 2 models:

- Sport (with attribute name and relationShip players)
- Player (with attribute name and relationShip sport)

In a ViewController, I wan't to display all players in a UITableView ordered by sport.
When a player name changes, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate callbacks are called.

But when the name of a Sport is updated, no NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate callbacks are called.

Is this a normal behaviour ? How can I know the updates of Sport.name (without creating another NSFetchedResultsController) ?

Thank you and Best Regards.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sport.name != NULL"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sport.name" ascending:YES], 
                              [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES],
                              nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Player" 
                                         inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];


fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                          managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext 
                                         sectionNameKeyPath:@"sport.name" 
                                               cacheName:nil];
[fetchRequest release];

fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;


NSError *error = nil;
if ([fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error] == NO) {
     ALog(@"Fetch error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using a tip:

```
 If (fetchresultcontroller != nil || isOtherEnthityUpdate)
 {
      return fetchresultcontroller;
 }
```

And do self.tableview reload from any place where u check other entity. It can be notification center or other tableview.